# Form still submits even though validation returns false

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I use the generic alert box the form validation works ok but if I try to make the alert box look nice using a JQuery script the form validates and submits despite the value returned being false

The standard alert box which works

```
function validate(){
    if( document.audit_form.audit_name.value == "" )
       {
         alert( "Please select a name for your audit" );
         document.audit_form.audit_type.focus() ;
         return false;
     }
return true;
}
```

Attempt one with jQuery MsgBox from codecanyon

```
function validate(){
    if( document.audit_form.audit_name.value == "" )
       {
         $.msgbox("Please select an audit type", 
                    {
                        type:"alert",
                        buttons: [
                            {type: "submit", value: "Ok"}
                        ]
                    },
                    function(result){

                    if (result && result=='Ok'){
                        return false;
                    }
            });
       }
return true();
}
```

Attempt two with Apprise

```
function validate(){
    if( document.audit_form.audit_name.value == "" )
       {
         apprise('Please enter a name for your audit?', {'textOk' : 'Ok',}, function(r) {

            if(r) { 
                return( true );
            } else { 
                return (false);
            }
        });
       }
}
```

In all three instances the alert box displays when it should but with the JQuery versions the form still submits.  The functions are called using

```
 <form id="audit_form" name="audit_form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" 
action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" onsubmit="return validate();">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both `$.msgbox` and  `apprise` are not blocking functions and the result is returned before functions' callback, you should change your logic. Basically that's how your form submit [should](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) look like:

```
$('#audit_form').submit(function(event){
     event.preventDefault();
     yourUIAlertFunction(..., ..., function(isSuccess){
          if(isSuccess){
              submitFormLogic();
          } else {
              hideAlertAndShowErrors();
          }
     });
});
```

Comment: Thank, any advice as to the changes to make?

Comment: Vi, thanks, I'm just trying to work out how I would apply it to either of the jquery functions so I can style my alert boxes.  I'm fairly new to javascript etc